# NSData Exception - "incomprehensible archive"

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

So I got an exception while trying to implement `NSKeyedUnarchiver` because I'm trying to save an array of custom objects with `NSUsersDefaults`. Because I kept on getting an error saying that I had non-properties in it I decided to archive them into `NSData`. Now I'm getting this error: "incomprehensible archive".

Here is how I am archiving (I've tested all objects to be null, non of them are):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anotherArray];
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    CustomObj *obj = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *newdata  = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newdata];
}
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
[coder setObject:newArray forKey:@"key"];
```

Here is how I am unarchiving(again everything is tested for null):

```
if (!arrayM) { arrayM = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; NSLog(@"initialized"); }
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayM.count; i++) {
        NSData *data = [arrayM objectAtIndex:i];
        --> The exception happens here: CustomObj *obj  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        [arrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:obj];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't archive it with NSKeyedArchiver, so why would you expect that you would be able to use NSKeyedUnarchiver to get the data back?  The way you want to do it is like this.  Make your custom object conform to the NSCoding protocol, and implement its two methods (encode and decode).  Then you can archive with NSKeyedArchiver on your array of custom objects.  The NSKeyedArchiver will call encodeWithCoder on each object, and any objects it contains (if it is a collection).

EDIT:  Call NSKeyedArchiver on the **array**, not each object.  Then when you unarchive it, unarchive it into an array again.

Comment: It's still giving me the same error when I changed it to the current code above. And I do have the encode methods in place.

Comment: @ManOx So you are calling the keyed archiver on the array, getting back data, and setting that data in your defaults?  Then when you read it back you get the data out of defaults and call unarchive into an NSArray?

Comment: Yep, I've archived the Projects and I've archived the entire array. Neither worked.